# Non-rigorous math books

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I’m self-studying physics and mathematics out of interest and I am looking for some non-rigorous (text)books on mathematics. Perhaps one book covering all areas relevant to physics or separate books in the areas of non-linear dynamics, differential equations, differential geometry, group theory, etc. 
I am explicitly looking for non-rigorous, intuitive approaches to these fields. I feel overly rigorous books make the material needlessly difficult (to me often impossible) and slow to read.  I am looking for things in the style of student’s guides, such as Dan Fleisch’s “A Student’s guide to vectors and tensors” but then more expanded:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11925464-a-student-s-guide-to-vectors-and-tensors?ac=1&from_search=true

Also, a mathematics book that shows the bigger picture on mathematics would be of interest. Something more or less popularising.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)?

Comment: Maybe Penrose's Road to Reality?

Comment: To be called mathematics, it cannot be nonrigorous. Mathematicians are well aware of the dangers of heuristic/intuitive mathematics since at least the beginning of the 20th century. See the controversies surrounding the italian school of geometry, and recently nonrigorous mathematics such as the grossone numbers

Answer (score 0):

"[The Theoretical Minimum](https://theoreticalminimum.com/)" seems aimed at what you seek. This covers all of the math subjects needed for QM and GR at an introductory textbook level with a minimum of elaboration. It assumes algebra and introductory calculus as prerequisites although it reviews some key points of those.

Comment: I am looking for something in-between The Theoretical Minimum and actual rigorous textbooks still. I have read (and enjoyed) these books but I would like to dig a little deeper. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Group Theory: an Intuitive Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9810233655) by Ron Mirman.  This does a nice job "talking" the reader through a lot of the material and using examples to introduce some concepts sometimes presented completely without context and thus difficult appreciate.

It is not overly rigorous and I do not think Mirman is good enough as a stand-alone text, but as a companion to go with something a little more rigorous - like Cornwell's [Group theory in physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0121898008), Mirman is very useful to lessen the slope of the learning curve of this topic.